# Remove XML node using XSLT not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following the first lines of an XML file I want to remove Id node with its children nodes inside InitgPty only.

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>0001</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2017-10-27T07:00:53</CreDtTm>
      <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>84562.00</CtrlSum>
      <InitgPty>
        <Nm>ABC Co</Nm>
        <Id>
          <OrgId />
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
```

After reading a lot I tried this XSLT but with no luck:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
 version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://www.six-interbank-clearing.com/de/pain.001.001.03.ch.02.xsd" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.six-interbank-clearing.com/de/pain.001.001.03.ch.02.xsd pain.001.001.03.ch.02.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}" >
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>



 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <Document xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.six-interbank-clearing.com/de/pain.001.001.03.ch.02.xsd pain.001.001.03.ch.02.xsd">
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </Document >
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="InitgPty/Id"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I added the below line :

```
<xsl:template match="InitgPty/Id"/>
```

I need your help to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to archive this, since you can match on attributes too.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl template match="InitgPty/Id"/>
```

If you want to copy comments too use:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Edit: Try this one, if the upper code is not working:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Id' and parent::node()[local-name() = 'InitgPty']"/> 
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:copy> 
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The suggestion didn't work form me? I did remove my line and added yours

Comment: Weird. Are you sure, that your node has exactly that name and you havent changed the document yet?

Another way to archive this would be:

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Id' and parent::node()[local-name() = 'InitgPty']"/>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: This one works! Please update your answer so I can mark it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I guess it was because of the namespace then. Will do :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [@christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5009186/christian-mosz)  seems correct to me, but if it doesn't work try with an explicit prefix, for example

```
<xsl template match="ns:InitgPty/ns:Id" xmlns:ns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.0'/>
```

Comment: Neither suggestions worked! What could be the reason?